# Uso de excepcion BramantiException

Tags: java, xml

Quiero convertir un Xml a un objeto de Java pero no me reconoce  `BramantiException` les dejo el código:

```
public static Factura convertirXMLAObjeto(String cadenaXML) throws BramantiException {
        Factura factura = new Factura();
        try {
            JAXBContext contextoJAXB = JAXBContext.newInstance(Factura.class);
            Unmarshaller um = contextoJAXB.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader readerResultado = new StringReader(cadenaXML);
            factura = (Factura) um.unmarshal(readerResultado);
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
             throw new BramantiException(ex.getMessage(), ex);

        }
        return factura;
    }
```

Comment: Hola puedes añadir el error que te genera el código?

Comment: BramantiException cannot be resolved to a type esto es lo que me sale!

Comment: ¿Y has importado esa clase?

Comment: @Moroni, como curiosidad, ¿De donde estas realizando este ejemplo?

Comment: Pues en una pagina como convertir de un xml a un objeto! pero no funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa clase no es parte del SDK probablemente estas realizando un tutorial, en este caso puedes crear tu mismo una clase en la cual imprimas el mensaje de error de tipo `JAXBException`.

```
private static class BramantiException extends Exception {
    public BramantiException(String message, JAXBException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Puedes crearla dentro de la clase que contiene el método `convertirXMLAObjeto()` , ejemplo:

```
     ...
     ...
     public static Factura convertirXMLAObjeto(String cadenaXML) throws BramantiException {
        Factura factura = new Factura();
        try {
            JAXBContext contextoJAXB = JAXBContext.newInstance(Factura.class);
            Unmarshaller um = contextoJAXB.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader readerResultado = new StringReader(cadenaXML);
            factura = (Factura) um.unmarshal(readerResultado);
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
             throw new BramantiException(ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } 
        return factura;
    }

    private static class BramantiException extends Exception {
        public BramantiException(String message, JAXBException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: me dio como resultado esto:

Comment: 14:20:33,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
14:20:33,371 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)  - with linked exception:
14:20:33,371 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
14:20:33,371 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)  - with linked exception:
14:20:33,371 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 408; columnNumber: 1124; Content is not allowed in trailing section.]]

Comment: Eso no tiene en realidad que ver con la pregunta, si deseabas preguntar como crear un xml en realidad tu pregunta debería tener otro formato y más información considera revisar [ask], saludos.